# Extracting data from JSON / dictionary with Python

Tags: python

I have an output :

```
result  = {
    "sip_domains":{
        "prefix":[{"name":""}],
        "domain":[{"name":"k200.com"},{"name":"Zinga.com"},{"name":"rambo.com"}]
    },
    "sip_security":{"level":2},
    "sip_trusted_hosts":{"host":[]},
    "sip_proxy_mode":{"handle_requests":1}
}
```

from this i just wanted the output to print to my screen :

```
domain : k200.com 
domain : Zinga.com 
domain : rambo.com
```

how can i get this output using regular expression

Help needed urgently

Comment: Why do you need regexes? You have the domains right there...

Comment: Why use regular expressions when it's already in a dictionary that you can traverse ?

Comment: I think it is not clear here if you've got an actual python dictionary or a string format (like json). Could you clearify this?

Comment: Also people don't care whether you need help urgently or tomorrow. Ther is no point of putting up a sad face to gain help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are getting this data as a string from somewhere you must convert it to a python dictionary object to access it.  You should not have to use any regular expressions to get this output.

```
import json
# get the json str somehow
json_dict = json.loads(json_str)
for domain_dict in json_dict['sip_domains']['domain']:
  print 'domain : %s' % (domain_dict['name'])
```

Answer (score 4):

If it's the text you need to parse then Use JSON module to parse the JSON payload:

http://docs.python.org/library/json.html?highlight=json#json

Regular expression are not needed with good programming language like Python.

Otherwise if it's Python dictionary then use Python dictionary [] style item access to read data from the dictionary.

Comment: Use json.loads() function to create Python dictionary from the string, then use dictionary access to read the values